# Add, enable and disable NLog loggers programmatically

Tags: c#, nlog

How can I add, edit, delete, enable, and disable loggers from code for NLog?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To add:

```
var logTarget = new ...
logTarget.Layout = "Your layout format here";
// e.g. "${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";

// specify what gets logged to the above target
var loggingRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, logTarget);

// add target and rule to configuration
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("targetName", logTarget);
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(loggingRule);
LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
```

Removal is done with

```
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Remove(loggingRule);
LogManager.Configuration.Reload();
```

Comment: Does Reload reread the config ?if not how can i reread the config ? in case i added targets etc to the config directly ?

Comment: @Stacker: Why would you want to add targets to the config directly?

Comment: the thing is i already have loggers that log the system , all i need is the ability to enable them disable them at runtime , maybe disable them by loglevel too , so i was thinking of editing the config file then make the logmanager reload it (reconfigure it from config file)

Comment: @Stacker: That's a very roundabout way of doing so. You already have the API to enable and disable loggers: add or remove the rules that feed log events to them, as above.

Comment: well how do i save changes to config file then ?

Comment: i like your approach, and i got how to reload the config ,its by adding the following :
<Nlog autoReload="True".......

Comment: @Stacker: Glad to hear you solved it in the meantime. Cheers!

Comment: As I can see the easiest way to disable or enable all logs: LogManager.EnableLogging() and LogManager.DisableLogging()

Comment: @Stacker According to the docs ( http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/M_NLog_Config_LoggingConfiguration_Reload.htm ) - `Reload()` is called by the LogManager when the config has changed, so calling `LogManager.Configuration.Reload();` is not going to reload the config.

Comment: @LasseChristiansen I read that differently.  When LogManager detects that the config file has changed (due to autoReload being turned on) it calls Reload as its way of reloading the configuration.  Reload does not actually change the configuration, unless you do LogManager.Configuration = LogManager.Configuration.Reload();

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old answer but I wanted give feedback for anyone looking to make modifications to their targets and logging rules programmatically that Configuration.Reload() doesn't work.

To update existing targets programmatically you need to use the ReconfigExistingLoggers method:

```
var target = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("logfile");
target.FileName = "${logDirectory}/file2.txt";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

An example that adds and removes logging rules on the fly:

```
if (VerboseLogging && !LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Contains(VerboseLoggingRule))
{
    LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(VerboseLoggingRule);
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
else if (!VerboseLogging && LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Contains(VerboseLoggingRule))
{
    LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Remove(VerboseLoggingRule);
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}
```

As written in docs:

> Loops through all loggers previously returned by GetLogger. and
>   recalculates their target and filter list. Useful after modifying the
>   configuration programmatically to ensure that all loggers have been
>   properly configured.

This answer and sample comes from Tony's answer in:

[Update NLog target filename at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756777/update-nlog-target-filename-at-runtime)

Comment: Thank you! I spent several hours trying to find out why my config changes weren't propagating to my Log object. NLog has gotten way to convoluted IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

NLog 4.6.7 makes it possible to assign Layout-variables to LoggingRule-levels, and change these Layout-variables at runtime.

```
<nlog>
    <variable name="myLevel" value="Warn" />
    <rules>
      <logger minLevel="${var:myLevel}" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then you can do this in code:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["myLevel"] = "Debug";
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules