# Delete Nlog log file after it was successfully emailed

Tags: c#, outlook, nlog

I want to delete my Nlog logfile between each application run only if it was emailed to me successfully otherwise it should keep adding to the logfile. I am using Outlook to email the file. I don't want to use Smtp since some networks block port 25 and then it does not get emailed to me.

The problem is when I try to delete the logfile with File.Delete(logfile) is says that the the file is in use by aonther process. How do I unlock or close the file in order for me to email it using Outlook (and then re-open it fo further logging)?

I was thinking of making a copy of the logfile and emailing that, but I'm not sure if its the best way to do it.

Thx for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Outlook which prevents the deletion of the file - your application is still running and logging to that file is still active, hence it is the Nlog part of your application which prevents the deletion. 
Tell nlog to use a different log file, or not to log at all (you may resume logging later on).

Answer (score 1):

By default nlog doesn't keep files open (file target, keepFileOpen). So either you try to delete file when your application is writing data, or outlook still using the file.

First, you may want to send it via outlook a copy of the log file. So you'd be sure that original file is not locked by an external process.

Second, you'll be able to reconfigure current file target to write to another file (`log(n+1).txt` or something. There are some hints about programmatic configuration at [Add, enable and disable NLog loggers programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471490/add-enable-and-disable-nlog-loggers-programmatically)). So you'll be sure that application isn't logging to the file.

Then you'll be able to remove it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :

```
if(chkLogger.Checked){
    NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForFileLogging("Logfile.log",NLog.LogLevel.Trace);
}
else
{
 NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForFileLogging("Logfile.log", NLog.LogLevel.Off);
}
```

Option 2 : LogManager.DisableLogging() and LogManager.EnableLogging()

from website [Stopping-Starting-NLog-on-runtime](http://nlog-forum.1685105.n2.nabble.com/Stopping-Starting-NLog-on-runtime-td1685945.html)